# How to style <a> tags independently?

Tags: html, css

How should I make anchor tags independent from each other, so changing size of one of them won't affect others?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" - downvote button tooltip

Comment: Uh sorry. Still haven't quite figured out when to answer and when not to.

Comment: Why the people are downvoting the question? Unnecessary — the question was objectively. Probably our buddy doesn't have any syntax but need a light to make his cookies in HTML. Keep calm, gentlemen. @Zenith Maybe  he did not know what to look for.

Comment: @chiefGui Read the about page. Excerpt: "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: @xec Thinking in this way, you're right.

Answer (score 4):

Give them a css class?

```
<a href='http://google.com' class='class1'>Google</a>
<a href='http://yahoo.com' class='class2'>Yahoo</a>

a.class1{border:1px solid #ff9900;}
a.class2{border:1px solid #ff0099;}
```

Or use wrapping elements

```
<div class='class-a'>
  <a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>
  <a href='http://yahoo.com'>Yahoo</a>
</div>

<div class='class-b'>
  <a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>
  <a href='http://yahoo.com'>Yahoo</a>
</div>

div.class-a a{background-color:red;}
div.class-b a{background-color:blue;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should give them individual CSS classes:

In your CSS:

```
a.this { ... }
a.that { ... }
```

In your HTML:

```
<a href='' class='this'>...</a>
<a href='' class='that'>...</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can categorize your anchors using classes.

CSS:

```
a.red {
   color: red;
}

a.blue {
   color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="red">Hello!</a>
<a href="#" class="blue">Bye!</a>
```

Your output will be anchors in red and blue, respectively.

Take a look [here, on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn5J5/) to play.

Answer (score 1):

add id or class to them

html:

```
<a href="..." class="anchor1">Anchor 1</a>
<a href="..." class="anchor2">Anchor 2</a>
```

css:

```
.anchor1{
   color: red;
}

.anchor2{
   color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="someClass">Link</a>

.someClass { /* your styles here */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add different CSS styling to your  tags (or any HTML elements) use ID or CLASS.

Please note an important concept that ID's should only be used once, while classes are supposed to be used for multiple items of the same element but not all of them e.g.:
Using CLASS: (Link 1 is size 20, and links 2 & 3 are size 10, while Link 3 is set to the default size)

```
<a href="#" class="anchor1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor2">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor3">Link 4</a>

<style>
.anchor1{
   font-size:20px;
}

.anchor2{
   font-size:10px;
}
</style>
```

Using ID: (Link 1 is size 20, and link 2 is size 10, while Links 3 & 4 are set to the default size.)

```
    <a href="#" id="anchor1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="anchor2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="anchor3">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="anchor4">Link 4</a>

<style>
#anchor1{
   font-size:20px;
}

#anchor2{
   font-size:10px;
}
</style>
```

For a more in-depth explanation of when to use ID vs CLASS please see [this guide](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp).